# Background image with z-index not fully transparent

Tags: css

Im writing a tank-game in dart. It's 27 * 27 table. For every single field I use `background-image` attribute. For example my tank consits of 4 small fields. Tank takes only 1 small field on raster. But through  pseudo-class `.bg-player-left:before` if achieved, that tank looks like it 4 field-tank. Same idea with bullets. It takes only one field on raster, but looks like 2. The problem is, that top-left position of this objects is always black.

[image]

```
        .bg-water {
        background-image: url("../img/water-field.png");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .bg-bush {
        background-image: url("../img/bush-field.png");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
.bg-bullet-up, .bg-bullet-down, .bg-bullet-left, .bg-bullet-right,
.bg-player-up, .bg-player-down, .bg-player-left, .bg-player-right {
    position: relative;
}

.bg-player-up:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    right: -15px;
    bottom: -15px;
    background-image: url("../img/player-tank-left.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
}

.bg-bullet-up:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    right: -15px;
    bottom: -15px;
    background-image: url("../img/bullet-left.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You can also try by yourself (https://javajunikorn.github.io/BattleCity/build/web/html/test.html)
In order to move tank you need to start the game from mobile or in browser inspector for mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

interesting idea to morph the object with pseudoclass.

Could it be that you have a css color background set to black, which on that png for bullet and tank creates this distortion?
If I go here: https://javajunikorn.github.io/BattleCity/build/web/img/bullet-left.png

I can see this attribute in css:

background: #0e0e0e;

Comment: But it should be overwritten by `background-img`. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: normally it should, but the img is a transparent png.

Comment: black background I found only for `td` elements. If I disable it in inspector, it want change anything. The problem stays same. Another place, where background black ist, i didnt found

Comment: if you disable the img of the tank in inspector you can see a td colored td element. this element is causing the issue, in my understanding

Comment: if you dont scale the img up with pseudo classes this error is not appearign in inspector view. what could also work is to set the background-color:transparent on the ::before td class.

Comment: But I dont know another way, how to make element, that takes one table cell, to look like 4 cell...

Comment: well, somehow the background in td is getting set. Try to set background-color: transparent; maybe it help. Otherwise check where the tank/bullet is and give it the same background.